# How to create an RTSP server to stream from webcam?

Tags: java, windows, ffmpeg, webcam, rtsp

I want to create an RTSP streaming server using my integrated webcam and later on using the same stream server to click pictures using java code. I did some research and there are several options available such as FFmpeg, wowza, etc but I don't know how to use them properly. I am using windows OS. I want the streaming server to be localhost. And i can use this link to actually take pictures in java.

Comment: I would suggest that you pick an option and try to implement it. When you get stuck with specific questions, please post them for us to help you. If you are just asking for advice on which solution to use, you should probably ask it here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This [rpos project by Jeroen Versteege](https://github.com/BreeeZe/rpos) looks promising. It turns a PI into an ONVIF/RTSP server. The build steps looks long from its repo page. It will take some effort to get it to compile and run for other platforms. The project won [an ONVIF challenge top 10](https://www.onvif.org/blog/blog/2018/07/12/onvif-challenge-announces-top-10/).

To debug or otherwise help testing the server, you may look into another top 10 winner in the same challenge: an [ONVIF viewer by Casper Meijin](https://gitlab.com/caspermeijn/onvifviewer).

Hope the information can get you started. Though not a complete solution to date (Nov of 2019).